# CGI table programming with Perl: Can I use if-statements or loops within the format?

Tags: perl, cgi

For example, could I use an if-statement in the middle of the Perl code in order to make a number of rows?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: A CGI script in Perl is just a Perl script that writes to standard output what you want to see in the browser. So, yes you can.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you have something like

```
print
   table(
      Tr(
         td(...),
         td(...),
         td(...),
      ),
      Tr(
         td(...),
         td(...),
         td(...),
      ),
      Tr(
         td(...),
         td(...),
         td(...),
      ),
   );
```

and you want to use loops and conditionals inside the call to `table`.

You cannot place *statements* (including `if (...) { ... }` and `for (...) { ... }`) in the middle of an *expression* (such as a subroutine call). But you achieve what you want through the use of intermediate storage.

Procedural approach:

```
my @trs;
for my $row (...) {
   my @tds;
   for my $field (@$row) {
      push @tds, td($field);
   }

   push @trs, Tr(@tds);
}

print table(@trs);
```

Functional approach:

```
print
   table(
      map {
         Tr(
            map {
               td($_)
            } @$_
         )
      } ...
   );
```

Comment: The `CGI` uses actually `Tr` to avoid clash with `tr///` operator.